# How to map a postgres money column in MS Access?

Tags: postgresql, ms-access, postgresql-9.1

I have a [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) database. In some tables there are columns of type `money`.

I'd like to use `MS Access` as a front-end.

But while linking the table in MS Access using postgres odbc driver, the columns of type money all have a value of 0. While trying to update the value an error is shown:

```nong
operator does not exist: money = double precision
```

The datatype in the linked table is NUMBER `(FieldSize = DOUBLE)`and it cannot be changed to currency.

I do not want to change the datatype in postgres from money to numeric. (But maybe, I have to?)

Hopefully some one can help.

Thanks.

Comment: [Don't use money](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_money)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think the best way to do this is to change the column data type in PostgreSQL to numeric. The good news is you can convert the columns without loosing precision.

I've tried it out and another way to do it is to create views for each of the tables containing money values that cast the columns to the numeric data type. You can then define update, insert, and delete INSTEAD OF triggers to make the views update-able, and cast the types in the trigger functions back to money. In this case the PostgreSQL engine is doing the conversion instead of the ODBC driver or Access. While this solution works, it is more complicated and brittle than just converting the column data types.

Both of the above solutions will make your data sheets update-able.

BTW, you can convert the numeric back to a currency on the Access side with `CCur(columnname)`.

Comment: Yes, the best would be to change the datatype. Thank you, especially for the CCur(columnname) tip.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting it to numeric:

```
# select 2::double precision::money;
ERROR:  cannot cast type double precision to money
LINE 1: select 2.0::double precision::money;
                                    ^
# select 2::double precision::numeric::money;
 money 
-------
 $2.00
(1 row)

# select 2::money::double precision;
ERROR:  cannot cast type money to double precision
LINE 1: select 2::money::double precision;
                       ^
# select 2::money::numeric::double precision;
 float8 
--------
      2
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thx Denis. But I can not write/modify the query msaccess uses to query the database. Or I do not know how?

Comment: I haven't used Access in ages, so I'm afraid I won't be able to be of much more help. But try using `CAST`. I'd be surprised if you cannot use it. e.g. `CAST(money_field as numeric)`

Answer (score 0):

I can recreate the issue (at least partially), and it definitely seems to be some weird interaction between the Access user interface, the Access Database Engine, and the PostgreSQL ODBC driver. I have an Access linked table named [public_table1] which is linked to the PostgreSQL table

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  customer character varying(255),
  balance money,
  CONSTRAINT pk_table1 PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE table1
  OWNER TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE table1 TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE table1 TO public;
```

I can open the linked table in Datasheet View and I do see the [balance] values but I cannot edit them (same error as you). If I use the Access query builder to build an Update query like this...

```
UPDATE public_table1 SET public_table1.balance = 2.22
WHERE (((public_table1.[id])=4));
```

...I also get the error. However, the following VBA statement works fine:

```
Sub pgTest()
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE public_table1 SET balance=6.78 WHERE id=4", dbFailOnError
End Sub
```

So, at least in my case, it appears that I could use datasheets and bound forms to *view* the PostgreSQL data but not *change* it. Unfortunately, that limitation could significantly reduce the benefits of using Access as a front-end (depending on what sort of operations you intended to perform).

Comment: Thank you very much. Which locale are you using on Postgres-Server? And which language is your Windows? Maybe that's the reason that I could not see the values. I have tried `de_DE.UTF-8` and `de_DE.iso88591` on the server. I have a german windows.

Comment: @mara I am using an English-language copy of Windows and my PostgreSQL database is using `UTF-8` for `ENCODING`, and `English_United States.1252` for `LC_COLLATE` and `LC_CTYPE`.